# Grails HasMany Scaffolding

Tags: grails, has-many, scaffolding

Im new to Grails and wanted to model a HasMany-Relationship like follows:

```
class Comment {
    String content

    static constraints = {}
}


class Text {
    String content

    static hasMany = [comments: Comment]

    static constraints = {}
}
```

The Problem is, that the scaffolding of this doesn't work, it produces an error when calling the create view. I am using Grails 2.0.4. After using the search I came to [this stack overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/823137/grails-dynamic-scaffold-with-hasmany-is-it-a-bug-or-am-i-misconfiguring).

They discuss the same error, but they say, that they changed the views manually. My question as a newcomer is: How can I change the view, so that I can do many comments on one single Text?

Greetz

Comment: Well. I tested it on my machine (ubuntu 12.04/grails 2.0.4). And it works as expected. Could you post some more details (plugins, config, ...)

What exactly is the error? Is there some output?